# How to configure Postfix mail to act as a SMTP server for my Windows PHP to send mail?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, php, configuration, email

I am trying to send mail from PHP on Windows. I want to configure my Ubuntu to accept requests from Windows PHP mail(). How can I do it?

Comment: be more precise please. It's hard to understand what you really want, without knowing, your servers version, your purpose of sending mail and so on.

Comment: @Anarko_Bizounours, Server is Ubuntu 11.04, purpose is for testing. I have a Windows machine where I develop, I want to have PHP send mail somehow. So I think I can use the mail from my Ubuntu, I need to somehow connect the 2. what else do u need to know?

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand, i think you can use the php function [mail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

It's much more easy to use, than trying to connect your windows to you ubuntu to use mailto shell cmd. Just check that you have the package needed, and try it out, with you own mail. I think it'll work fine.

Have a nice day.